# How to pause a HTML5 video on an event?

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I am building a website with HTML5-`<video>` in fullscreen background. There are pages in shape of `<div>`s becoming visible with SWF-container player in them that cause serious CPU performance issues when both media play.
So I want to add a simple javascript command that pauses the background video when a project-`<div>` becomes visible. Would be nice if it resumes again the playback when it gets closed/hidden.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('myvideotag').pause();
```

Note that there is no stop() method. In the function that shows/hides your DIV, place the play/pause function there.

More resources here: http://www.digitaria.com/blogs/html5-video-skinning-tutorial-part-2-play-buttons

Comment: The pausing works. Thanks! I've read through the article you link. Very interesting, thanks again.


Now I want to resume the playback when a certain function is called (`<a href="#" onclick="hideTheDiv(...)">...</a>`) Is there something like a listening function in js that play()s when triggered so?

Edit:
I should mention that I only have limited access to the websites structure as I am working on a CMS template. I cannot reach into the specific anchor level to add a javascript function there by myself.

Comment: You would just use the `.play()` method in the function that should resume playback.

Comment: I thought so, hence my edit. I cannot add lines of code in that level. The script would be written into the text area of the CMS that contains the page's specific content. I think I would need a "surveilance" function in there that listenes if the specific function is called to action.

Comment: You can add scripts anywhere on the page using the SCRIPT tag.

Comment: I am aware of that. I think I want to use the EventListener method. Since I am somewhat dusted in Javascript, I think I have figure it myself. Still, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What event do you want to trigger play()?

Comment: I want the `onclick="hideTheDiv()"` to trigger the `play()`. As I said in my first comment.

Comment: And you cannot modify the `hideTheDiv()` function or the anchor tag?

Comment: No, the anchor and the linked js-file are out my reach. I tried an event handler to surveil the anchor. Does not work yet, any idea? :)

`<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('mainbg').pause();

function findFirstDescendant(parent, tagname)
{
   parent = document.getElementByClass(parent);
   var descendants = parent.getElementsByTagName(tagname);
   if ( descendants.length )
      return descendants[0];
   return null;
}

var header = findFirstDescendant("project_index", "a");

header.onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById('mainbg').play();
};

</script>`

Comment: Does the anchor that you want to have trigger the `play()` have a name or ID? I would assume it does not since you have that `findFirstDescendant` function.

Comment: Exactly. The anchor itself has no id, class or name. Just a href="#" and onclick="...". `'mainbg'` is the background video, `project_index` is the class of the `<div>` that contains the link. Sorry for the crappy format, the ``formatting`` didn't seem to work.

Comment: I got it to work! Didn't notice the CMS would parse line breaks to `<br />` … put it all in one line and infact, it works. Had to add the original onclick-function again, but it runs smoothly. Thank you very much Evan, you saved my evening :D

Comment: Alternate:
var allAnchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
 var theAnchor;
 for (var i = 0; i < allAnchors.length; i++)
 {
  if (allAnchors.item(i).parentNode.className == "project_index")
  {
   theAnchor = allAnchors.item(i);
   break;
  }
 }
 
 //Do whatever
 theAnchor.onclick = document.getElementById("mainbg").play();

Answer (score 4):

My personal favourite is a small onclick handler added to html attribute, like this:

```
<video onclick="this.paused? this.play() : this.pause()">
```

Answer (score 0):

since there are not traditional events on div hide/show you have to play() and pause() your video element when you call the functions that make your div appear/disappear