# How do I pause a HTML5 video with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

Initially the video is hidden. When you click the image with ID `3`, the video is visible. I put a button with ID `close_video` that will hide player. The problem is it's still running video after you click the button. How do I pause the video?

The code is:

```
<div id="video" class="popup-video">
  <div class="video">
    <div class="close_video" id="close_video">
    </div>
    <video id="id_video" width="400" height="257" controls="controls" preload="auto">
      <source src="{$content_dir}themes/trendy/video/Wildlife.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>     
    </video>                         
  </div>
</div>  

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#3').click(function(){
      $("#video").removeClass("popup-video").addClass("popup-video-show");
    });
  });
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#close_video').click(function(){
      $("#video").removeClass("popup-video-show").addClass("popup-video");
    });
  });
</script>
```

I also tried this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#close_video').click(function(){
      $("#video").removeClass("popup-video-show").addClass("popup-video");
      document.getElementById('id_video').pause();
      // and $("#id_video").pause();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Still no effect. The video disappears, but is still running.

Comment: I just googled your title and found the following topic : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155329/how-to-pause-a-html5-video-on-an-event

Comment: You could use: `$("#id_video").gt(0).pause();`

Answer (score 14):

When using jQuery, you'll need to use 'get' first:

```
$('#videoId').get(0).pause()
```

Comment: a tried $('#videoId').get(0).pause(),but error in firefox is: TypeError: $(...).get(...).pause is not a function

Comment: What version of Firefox are you running?

Comment: last version    20.0.1 firefox

Comment: TypeError: $(...).get(...).pause is not a function

Comment: @marius did you add the [jQuery Script](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery)?

Comment: Great! @maius look your page cache.

Comment: this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

When working with HTML5, use:

```
document.getElementById(\"movie_player\").click()
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you only need to click on the video to pause/play it.

Instead of using the `pause()` try to use the `click()`

Comment: i used click() but nothing effect