# On Button Click Pause HTML Video (Which is in autoplay)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML 5 video, and it plays without audio on page load. It works how I wanted. But is there a way the user can press a button and the video will pause?

My Code in HTML is:

```
<video autoplay loop poster="" id="bgvid">
<source src="img/bg.mp4" type="video/webm">
<source src="img/bg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

and the CSS...

```
video#bgvid { 
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
z-index: -100;
-ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
background: url(polina.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155329/how-to-pause-a-html5-video-on-an-event

Answer (score 1):

```
<video onclick="this.paused? this.play() : this.pause()">
```

As commented said. Via: [How to pause a HTML5 video on an event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155329/how-to-pause-a-html5-video-on-an-event)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.btn').click( function() {
   $('video').get(0).pause();
});

$('video').click( function() {
       this.pause();
});
```